# MongoDB Aggregation: Merging keys and summing values in nested objects

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm working on an aggregation pipeline in MongoDB using the PyMongo library (Python). I have a collection called "ip_range24_stats" that contains documents with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6093e34b4f16a024e43f0b94"),
  "as_num": "AS12345",
  "total_signals": 1000,
  "signals_per_scenario_1m": {
    "scenario1": 10,
    "scenario2": 20,
    "scenario3": 15
  }
}
```

The collection has a "category" field called "as_num" (representing an Autonomous System number), a "total_signals" field (representing the total number of signals), and an "signals_per_scenario_1m" field that contains a map of scenario names as keys and their respective signal counts as values.

I'm trying to write an aggregation pipeline to achieve the following:

Group the documents by "as_num".
Calculate the sum of "total_signals" for each "as_num".
Aggregate the "signals_per_scenario_1m" objects across the grouped documents, merging the keys and summing the values.
For example, given the following two documents:

Document 1:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6093e34b4f16a024e43f0b94"),
  "as_num": "AS12345",
  "total_signals": 1000,
  "signals_per_scenario_1m": {
    "scenario1": 10,
    "scenario2": 20,
    "scenario3": 15
  }
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6093e34b4f16a024e43f0b95"),
  "as_num": "AS12345",
  "total_signals": 1500,
  "signals_per_scenario_1m": {
    "scenario1": 5,
    "scenario2": 30,
    "scenario4": 25
  }
}
```

I would like the aggregation pipeline to produce the following result:

```
{
  "as_num": "AS12345",
  "total_signals": 2500,
  "signals_per_scenario_1m": {
    "scenario1": 15,
    "scenario2": 50,
    "scenario3": 15,
    "scenario4": 25
  }
}
```

### Attempts

I've attempted to write the aggregation pipeline using the $group and $project stages, but I'm encountering difficulties in correctly merging the keys and summing the values within the "signals_per_scenario_1m" objects.

Here's the current version of my pipeline:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = client['your_database']
collection = db['ip_range24_stats']
pipeline = [
    # Stage 1: Group documents by as_num and calculate sum of total_signals
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$as_num",
            "total_signals": {"$sum": "$total_signals"},
            "signals_per_scenario_1m": {"$push": "$signals_per_scenario_1m"},
        }
    },
    # Stage 2: Project the final result
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "as_num": "$_id",
            "total_signals": 1,
            "signals_per_scenario_1m": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$signals_per_scenario_1m",
                    "initialValue": {},
                    "in": {
                        "$mergeObjects": [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                "$arrayToObject": [
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "k": "$$this.k",
                                            "v": "$$this.v"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                }
            },
        }
    },
]
    
result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))
```

But it produces the following error

```
'$arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1'
```

Comment: As you've discovered, using any data as field names leads to future query pain.  Is it too late to change your data model to something like, `"signals_per_scenario_1m": [ {"senario": 1, "count": 10}, {"senario": 2, "count": 20}, {"senario": 3, "count": 15} ]`?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3LJt9zV5edq is the shortest that i was able to come up with. not the nicest of queies

Comment: @cmgchess sorry wrong copy paste, in the example it corresponds, to `total_signals` I will edit

Comment: @cmgchess despite the mistake in the statement, your suggestion is accurate, thank you!

Comment: And thanks @rickhg12hs for the suggestion, it looks like a better schema one should use in the future

Comment: Should I give as an answer or are you looking still looking for a better way

Comment: @cmgchess it's solved thanks to your comment above, I just can't mark it as solved since it's a comment